# Chose file name with Files.copy()

Tags: java

I have a temp file in `/tmp` that I want to archive somewhere so I tried:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
[...]

Path source = Paths.get("/tmp/path/to/file_123456789.xml");
Path destination = Paths.get("/path/to/archive/dir/file.xml");
Files.copy(source, destination).
```

This fails because :

> /path/to/archive/dir/file.xml is not a directory

I know it! But I just want to chose the destination file's name.

Up to now, I have some solutions which do not satisfy me:

- Create a temp directory with `Files.createTempDirectory` then move the temp file in it, rename it then move it to the destination directory.
- Copy the temp file in the archive directory then rename it there. But if the rename fails, I have some junk in the archive directory.
- Create an empty file in the archive directory and manually copy the content of the source file in it.

A cleaner solution probably exists. Do you know it?

Comment: That should be fine, so long as the *parent* directory exists.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oops. Yes, the parent directory does not exists. I assumed that intermediate directories would be created but this is not the case. I make a quick try. You are probably right :)

Comment: Admittedly the error message could be a lot more helpful too :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually, in my case, I do not know how but the *real* problem was that `/path/to/archive/dir` was actually a file. Do not ask me how I ended up with this as a file :) The error message is misleading. I write a self-answer with the test case to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Jon, I found that `/path/to/archive/dir` was actually a file. The error message is misleading because it says that `/path/to/archive/dir/file.xml` is not a directory even if the problem came from `/path/to/archive/dir`.

Steps to reproduce under linux :

1) create the file `/tmp/fakedir`

> touch /tmp/fakedir

2) In Java, execute this piece of code :

```
Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("test", "test");
Files.copy(tempFile, Paths.get("/tmp/fakedir/destination.xml"));
```

You get the error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /tmp/fakeDir/destination.xml: is not a directory
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copyFile(UnixCopyFile.java:243)
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(UnixCopyFile.java:581)
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:253)
  at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1271)
  at Test.main(Test.java:17)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```